# How to interpolate/keep values in Python

Tags: python

I would like to interact with a scene in real-time, let’s say for an example when I hold a key, the scale of an object doubles, ie with some sort of driver. As that’s either 1 or 0, the object is either small, or snaps into big. I am looking for a function to be able to dampen / lerp that value over a time to get a smooth transition (just as in Unity). Is something like that built in, or do I have to create that from scratch?

This [Unity script chapter on lerp/interpolation](https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/linear-interpolation#), I think that is clearer than I could describe it. I would love to use this function in Blender realtime with drivers, without KF interpolation.

Comment: tbh i don't really understand what you want (or mean). How can a scale either be one or 0 if the scale doubles? And why does it snap if you want to interpolate values? maybe make a sketch or link an animation how it should look like?

Comment: I am sorry, my description must have been confusing. In fact the example setup is quite simple, I will try better: Python detects a "keyboard.read_key()", and if a specific key is pressed, a Blender Driver lets say scales a sphere to a new value. Key not pressed sphere scale 1, key pressed sphere scale 2. As soon as I hit the key, the scale of the sphere "snaps" to the new value. I am looking for a way for 1 and 2 to interpolate over time t, in order to have a smooth transition animation in real time in the viewport.

Comment: you need to describe a specific issue you want to solve. your post lacks focus on the actual issue at hand you are trying to solve.

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: I think it's perfectly clear what he means. I don't think there's anything to do that builtin though, you'll have to do it from scratch.